# index 'enabled' fields good idea?

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational, database-indexes

Content of a website is stored in a MySQL database. 99% of the content will be enabled, but some (users, posts etc.) will be disabled. Most of the queries end as `WHERE (...) AND enabled`

Is it a good idea to create an index on the field 'enabled'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wouldn't be much use creating an index just on `enabled` alone. But it might be useful to create a compound index in which `enabled` is included, in order to achieve [ORDER BY optimisation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html).

For example if something like this was a common query:

```
SELECT * FROM things WHERE c1='foo' AND enabled=1 ORDER BY c2
```

An index on `c1` would allow the matching rows to be found quickly, but it would still need to be sorted in a separate step using `c2`.

An index on `c1, c2` should allow the ordering to be done from the index, greatly speeding up the query sorting, but the lack of `enabled` in the index would defeat that, because it'd have to compile the list of matching rows indexed by `c1`, *then* scan each row to check it's `enabled` before sorting the results by `c2`.

If the index were `enabled, c1, c2` or `c1, enabled, c2`, the whole WHERE condition and the ORDERing could be taken directly from index, giving faster results.

As always, it'll depend on what queries you're doing; you should [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html) your most-common queries to check for sure what it's doing.

Comment: Your thoughts were exactly what was missing to make a point. I decided to add enabled fields to the tables where I expect huge result sets. Because there is always an ORDER clause, this will decrease the scan time for the enabled rows. But for tables where I expect only a few matches, a one-by-one scan will not make a difference.